Should we allow questions of the form "check my work"?
If you go to the help center, you'll find it written there

don’t ask any questions about [...] [p]roofreading ("are there any mistakes?"), unless the source of concern is clearly specified

but I couldn't find any discussion on meta of the topic. I suspect the above rule was written in the early days of the community and never discussed, so I decided to see what you think:

Q: Are questions of the form "is the above text correct?" on topic or off topic?

P.S. This meta question is relevant, although it covers only one aspect, the spelling

In my opinion, they are off-topic in the same sense that any question that doesn't show a specific focus and previous research is.
If, after translating a paragraph or solving an exercise, one has one or more specific doubts, they are welcome to ask about them (provided that they are not answerable by simply looking up something). But simply reproducing a whole sentence or paragraph and asking to check it shows neither focus (are you possibly in doubt about every single word?) nor research (is this something you just dashed off? Google-translated? painstakingly worked out?).

I completely agree with @DaG answer. I think that another problem with this kind of questions is that they usually are "too localized" in the sense that they would be only useful to the OP, but they probably won't be of much help to other users. I believe that this kind of questions tend to be considered as off-topic along the StackExchange network (for instance, "check the errors in my code" or "check if my homework is OK"). So, in my opinion, they should be off-topic also on Italian.SE.
